# What is this white speck on the leaf of my plant?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-care, leaves, insects, basil

[image]

I found these tiny white web-like spots on many leaves of my plant. What are these specks? And what should I do with them?

1. Ignore them?
2. Wash/Wipe them away with water?
3. Pluck the infected leaves?

The plant is Holy Basil.

Comment: reminds me of a protective web over an insect egg.  Wipe them off and see if they return..

Comment: I will wipe them tomorrow. @kevinsky Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgetting the name of the bug, these bugs as I call simply milk bugs make these webs under the leaves to have there young. These bugs do eat the leaf so I would wipe them away and see if they return. No need to pluck away the leaf.